# How to get eclipse webby plugin to run webapp at root context

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jetty, webby

I recently changed from the eclipse m2e-wtp plugin to the webby plugin and I cannot get my webapp to run in the root context.  I've tried in both embedded jetty and installed tomcat and the result is always the same.

In the tomcat plugin I have

```
    <configuration>
      <path>/</path>
      <port>8080</port>
```

In the jetty plugin I have

```
    <configuration>
      <contextPath>/</contextPath>
```

In the "Web Project Settings" in eclipse I have the "Context root:" set as '/'.

In the debug confiugration for the project I have the "Context:" set as '/' and pointing to my installed tomcat6.

When I "debug as Webby" I still have to go to /project-name in order to see the webapp.  This worked without issue under m2e-wtp.  Is there other configuration I need to look at in order to get Webby to truly deploy to the root context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. Go to "Run > Run Configurations... "
2. Select the Webby run configuration
3. Change the context field to have two forward slashes instead of just one, i.e., '//'.

[image: Run Configuration for a project named minerva-web mounted at root context]

I'm not sure Webby was intended to work this way ... but it worked for me.  Before making this change I had to use localhost:9091/projectName.  After making the change I was able to go to localhost:9091.

Hope it works!